# Output a field to multiple json fields

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Is there a way using, Jackson annotations, to have a have given field serialised to 2 json fields.

Like the reverse of `@JsonAlias` which *deserialises* multiple json field to the one field.

Eg

```
class Foo {
    @SomeAnnotation("field2")
    String field1;
}
```

serialising as:

```
{
    "field1" : "xyz",
    "field2" : "xyz"
}
```

Is there a something like `@SomeAnnotation`?

——

Note: This is not a “should” I do this (it’s an imposed requirement), it’s a “how” I do this (elegantly).

Comment: Not the annotation-based solution you're looking for... but you can use 2 getters: `getField1()` and `getField2()` both returning `field1`.

Comment: @ernest_k post your idea as an answer. I have a feeling it will be accepted

Comment: I was thinking that an easy solution could come out of trying `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonAppend`. But seems that for properties, it may take a little more work (imo only worth it if this occurs often enough)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution to this may be to just add two getters for `field1`:

```
class Foo {
    private String field1 = "blah";

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field1;
    }
}
```

Jackson will create a field for each getter, following the javabeans naming convention:

```
{"field1":"blah","field2":"blah"}
```

An alternative to this may be `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter`, which can afford you even more flexibility:

```
class Foo {
    private String field1 = "blah";

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAny() {
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("field2", this.field1);
        m.put("field3", this.field1.toUpperCase());

        return m;
    }
}
```

Producing:

```
{"field1":"blah","field3":"BLAH","field2":"blah"}
```

Comment: I am using lombok, so there are only fields, but for simplicity, the wrapper getter wins.